# mimkit and mailkit can't refer in windowsphone project of xamarin.form

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

mailkit can't refer in windowsphone project of xamarin.form.

is mailkit not support windowsphone?

how can i do?

thanks

Install-Package MailKit

正在尝试解析依赖项“MimeKit (≥ 1.2.11.0)”。

正在安装“MailKit 1.2.11.1”。

已成功安装“MailKit 1.2.11.1”。

正在将“MailKit 1.2.11.1”添加到 PCLDemo.WinPhone。

正在卸载“MailKit 1.2.11.1”。

已成功卸载“MailKit 1.2.11.1”。

安装失败。正在回滚...

Install-Package : 无法安装程序包“MailKit 1.2.11.1”。您正在尝试将此程序包安装到某个将“WindowsPhone,Version=v8.1”作为目标的项目中，但此程序包不包含与该框架兼容的任何程序集引用或内容文件。有关详细信息，请与程序包作者联系。

所在位置 行:1 字符: 1

- Install-Package MailKit
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], 
    InvalidOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Xamarin.Forms project targets Windows Phone 8.0 and MailKit cannot target that version.

You might have better luck if you bump the Windows Phone target to 8.1.

Comment: The version of my window phone is windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

Comment: Can I use  the "mailkit"?

Comment: No, because you are using the Silverlight subset which doesn't include the full WindowsPhone 8.1 profile

Comment: thank you  very much, if i think use xamarin.form and Compatible with Windows phone ,what I can do?